# How can I get the score of each Prediction for a Multiclass Classification model

Tags: classification, multiclass-classification

I am just curious, and I wanted to know if it is possible to get the score of each prediction in a Multiclass Classification model. If it is possible, how can I implement this to make predictions on my original datasets and not the `test_data` and output the score of each prediction in a new column.

I made predictions on my original dataset to have the prediction columns named [predictions_final] I also want to make predictions on the original dataset to get the score or probabilities score to be in another column side by side with the prediction and my original dataset

````
########  BELOW IS THE CODE 


from sklearn.multiclass import OneVsRestClassifier

from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier

from sklearn.metrics import roc_curve, auc

import scikitplot as skplt

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X3,y1, test_size=0.2, random_state=10)

RFc = OneVsRestClassifier(RandomForestClassifier(max_features=0.2))

RFc.fit(X_train, y_train)

y_pred = RFc.predict(X_test)

pred_prob = RFc.predict_proba(X_test)

skplt.metrics.plot_roc_curve(y_test, pred_prob)
plt.show()


y_pred = RFc.predict(X_test)

from sklearn.metrics import classification_report,confusion_matrix
print(classification_report(y_test,y_pred))

preded = RFc.predict(X_test)

RFc.predict_proba(X_test)

Final = RFc.predict(X3)

X3['predictions_final']=Final
```
````

Comment: You should tell us at the very least if you use any ML library, e.g. scikit-learn, Keras, pytorch, etc, and, ideally, show us a snippet of your code to see how to answer your question accurately.

Comment: Thanks @noe I have added a snippet of my code. kindly go through it and see how you can help to answer the question

Answer (score 0):

for example:

```
model.fit(x, y ,epochs=3 validation_split=0.2)
prediction = model.predict(x_1)
```

this will output the scores for each class if i'm not mistaken

```
print(prediction[0])
>>[[0.1 , 0.7, 0.2 ,0.5]] "if they are 4 classes"
>>np.argmax(prediction[0]) "to get the actual class"
```

i don't know if this answers your question

Comment: Thanks @Tunechi. I will try this out and see if it works for me. Once again, I am grateful